# Referer sub array?

Tags: python, arrays, reference

I have an array orig[].
Now I want to create another array ref[] that refer to only **specific** elements in orig[].
By implying it is referrer I mean any change in element of ref[] will change the corresponding element of orig[].

F.e. pseudo code :

```
orig = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]
ref[0] ==> orig[2]
ref[1] ==> orig[4]
```

now if I do :

```
 ref[0] = 11
 ref[1] = 22
```

orig will become :

```
[ 1,2,11,4,22 ]
```

also when I ca do : for x in ref : ....

Comment: Python doesn't work like that. You should pick a different way to organize your data rather than digging into the messy kludges required to get something like this to almost work.

Comment: i was afraid it would be this way  ;(,  I was thinking of passing indexes around instead, but it is too kludgey.. i have to pass the array and the indexes, both.

Comment: @user1019129: If you really need this, it wouldn't be too hard to build.

Comment: can you use wrapper objects instead of straight integers? if yes, then store instances of the wrapper object in your first array, refer to the same instances in `ref[]` and then have a setter function to set the internal value of each instance

Comment: You can do something like it, but it would have to be like `ref[0] = (orig, 2)` (storing separate references to the "base" array and a certain index into it).  But even to do that you would have to write your own custom type for `ref` to produce the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the `list` class, and then implement all the methods that should behave differently than in a standard list.

Here is an implementation, but if you really would go ahead with this, you'd have to define a lot more methods:

```
class Referrer(list):
    def __init__(self, referredTo):
        self.__referredTo = referredTo

    def add_refs(self, *indexes):
        self.extend(indexes)

    # Redefine some of the methods that are invoked in certain syntax:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.__referredTo[list.__getitem__(self, index)]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.__referredTo[list.__getitem__(self, index)] = value

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self)):
            yield self[i]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([x for x in self])

# Example use:
orig = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ref = Referrer(orig)
ref.add_refs(2, 4)
ref[0] = 11
ref[1] = 22
print (orig) # [1, 2, 11, 4, 22]

for x in ref:
    print (x) # 11 and 22
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GQx8/12)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by building a simple class and having your lists contain objects of the class.  Your code would look something like

```
Class my_ref():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

orig = [my_ref(n) for n in range(1,6)]
```

... and I expect that you can see from here how it works.

Answer (score 0):

we will need to use an addition dictionary for mapping and set, get via function as follows:

```
orig = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

ref = []

mapper = {}  # dictionary mapping ref index againt orig index


def fill_lst(lst, index):
    for _ in range(index-len(lst)+1):
        lst.append(None)


def populate_lst(target_index, source_index):
    try:
        ref[target_index] = orig[source_index]
    except IndexError:
        fill_lst(ref, target_index)
        ref[target_index] = orig[source_index]
    mapper[target_index] = source_index


def set_lst_val(target_index, val):
    try:
        ref[target_index] = val
    except IndexError:
        fill_lst(ref, target_index)
        ref[target_index] = val
    orig[mapper[target_index]] = val


populate_lst(0, 2)
populate_lst(1, 4)

print ref  # [3, 5]

set_lst_val(0, 11)
set_lst_val(1, 22)

print orig  # [1, 2, 11, 4, 22]
```